# How do I have my king fight in battles?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

When I first played Crusader Kings 2 I remember my king participating in battles.  How do I get my king to take up arms and go out into battle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign your King as the leader of one of the three flanks of your army. To do this, select your army and click the blue name on one of the three flanks. Find and assign your King.

If you are in enemy territory, you will need to either have your army be on the move or switch from siege view to army view.

**Note**: There are certain things that may prevent you from doing this such as your "Title Revokation" law setting, and if you are serving a higher liege in their court actively.

*Note the blue names below*
[image: Notice the blue names]

Comment: How do you switch from siege view to army view? I've always had to start the army on a march (while paused or very quickly halting them to prevent the sieged holdings morale from recovering). This can be quite tedious, especially if you're attempting to bait an enemy army into either attacking you or holding still to be attacked on advantageous terrain.

Comment: I don't have the game available, but I recall in the last few patches if you are sieging a county there is a small tab on the side that can switch from siege view. Although that might just be county view and not Army. Unfortunately I haven't touched CK2 in a few months. I seem to recall a change recently though that allowed you to see your Army while stationary.